# Datepart of month in store procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, datepart

I declared @workingdatekey  as below.

I need to define @newdatekey by subtracting one month from @workingdatekey which showld be in yyyymmdd format.

Both @workingdatekey and @newdatekey are in yyyymmdd format.

```
  Declare @workingdatekey int
  set @workingdatekey =  CONVERT(int,CONVERT(varchar(20),GETDATE()-1,112))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @workingdatekey int
SET @workingdatekey =  CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(MONTH, -1,GETDATE()),112)

SELECT @workingdatekey

RESULT: 20140205
```

OR

```
DECLARE @workingdatekey int
SET @workingdatekey =  CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(MONTH, -1,GETDATE()),112) AS INT)

SELECT @workingdatekey

RESULT: 20140205
```

Either will get you the same result.

What you were trying to do `GETDATE()-1` subtracts a day from the current datetime. You need to use [`DATEADD()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function to add or subtract intervals to a datetime value.

Comment: I need that result to be 20140204

Comment: Your Question says you want to subtract a month from the date and show it in YYYYMMDD format. If you want to subtract a day from the current date you can use DAY inside the DATEADD() function something like this    DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())